# how to simplify this pseudocode

Tags: c++, pseudocode, ida

I have this pseudocode in IDA but I don't understand the result when I compiled it

```
__int64 v17 = 507890351016; 
__int64 v20 = 0;
auto test = *(WORD*)(*(uintptr_t*)v17 + v20);
```

the output of test is **48**, can someone explain what's going here and what the equivalent in c++

Comment: What is `WORD`?

Comment: Perhaps the definition in the Windows API which expands to `unsigned short`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie [Bird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Gc4QTqslN4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v17 is a 64 bit integer, v20 is a 64 bit integer. v17 seems to be a pointer and whatever is at that address is being dereferenced to a DWORD type and stored in test. Because v20 == 0, the offset from v17+v20 is 0.

The result is

```
int64_t v17 = 507890351016;
DWORD test = *(DWORD*)v17;
```